# removing space that turned into string in a list

Tags: python

I have a specific file that I extracted lines from and it had a lot of space in it after put these lines in a list

```
 lines_list = open('data\wonderland.txt').read().splitlines()
```

I end up with this result

```
['ï»¿ Down the Rabbit-Hole','','','','Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the','','bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the','',
```

I specifically want to delete the `''` from my list

Comment: `lines_list = [x for x in lines_list if x != '']` or `lines_list = [x for x in lines_list if len(x)>0]`

Comment: Not related to your issue, but note that Python requires the \ character in non-raw strings to be escaped as \\.  It "works" in your example because \w doesn't mean anything special, but you would have gotten a confusing error with a, b, f, n, r, t, u, v, or x after the \.

Answer (score 4):

Use the built-in [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
lines_list = list(filter(None, lines_list))
```

Output:

```
['ï»¿ Down the Rabbit-Hole', 'Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the', 'bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the']
```

Or just:

```
lines_list = [i for i in lines_list if i]
```

Which has the same output